# How to edit form of Definition

Tags: definition

In my project, in the section 1.1, I want to create a definition. When I use

\begin{definition}
abc
\end{definition}

the output goes as "Definition 1.11. abc"

I want to change the format of my definition to "1.1.1. Definition. abc"

How can I do that ? Thank you.

Comment: Do you use a package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem` to help manage the appearance of theorem-like environments, including an environment named `definition`? If so, how do you define the `definition` environment, and is its definition (pun intended) tied to the definition of another theorem-like environment? Finally, is section "1.1" contained in chapter numbered "1"?

Comment: yeah I use package amsthm, my section 1.1 is contained in chapter 1. So what I look for is just  kind of  1.1.1. Definition.    1.1.2. Theorem.    1.1.3. Lemma.     1.1.4. Example ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using one of the standard document classes, your current preamble code likely contains an instruction similar to

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
```

I suggest you change it to

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

If that doesn't work for you (possibly because you use an uncommon document class), I suggest you execute

```
\counterwithin{theorem}{section}
```

after setting up the theorem-like environments.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition} % optional
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

%\counterwithin{theorem}{section} % alternate solution

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{chapter} % just for this example
\stepcounter{section}

\begin{theorem}    aaa aaa \end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}      bbb bbb \end{lemma}
\begin{definition} ccc ccc \end{definition}
\begin{example}    ddd ddd \end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how can I swtitch the number of the theorem to the front and then the word "Definition" goes to the back ? Like "1.1.1. Theorem." ?

Comment: @PermQi - Your follow-up question is answered in Section 4.2, "Number swapping", of the user guide of the `amsthm` package. To bring up the user guide in a pdf viewer, type `texdoc amsthm` at a command prompt. (Remark: Give executing `\swapnumbers` immediately after `\usepackage{amsthm}` a try.  Observe that a period (aka full stop) will be placed after the name of the theorem-like environment rather than after the number.)

Comment: I did just like your guidance and my output goes as "1.11 Definition. " The output is missing a dot in the number "1.11" while it should have been "1.1.1", and I don't know why. Maybe I did some code related to the counting inside the section. So how can I fix this without doing anything to the rest of my project ?

Comment: @PermQi - Did you change `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]` to `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`? If that's not applicable, did you try running `\counterwithin{<theorem>}{section}`, where `<theorem>` is the primary theorem-like environment?

Comment: I think my problem is since my chapter is 1 and my section is 1.1, so the definition some how is numbered from 1.11 with missing a dot between 1 and 1. I think it has nothing to do with the \counterwithin{<theorem>}{section}, I think it is an issue with the format of title of the environment. Do you think the code \renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.} would fix this ?

Comment: @PermQi - The example I provided, which employs the `report` document class, does *not* experience any of the issues you say you're encountering. Unfortunately, , you've have not (yet) seen fit to let me know which document class you use, and you haven't communicated either how exactly you define the theorem-like environments. Without these crucial pieces of information, I can't meaningfully help you any further.

Comment: here is my source code 
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\hspace{-0.3cm}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{17}{20}\selectfont}
\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

Comment: @PermQi - So the culprit is likely `\hspace{-0.3cm}` in `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\hspace{-0.3cm}}`. What's the purpose of the backward spacing? Does the problem with the numbering of the theorem-like environments persist if you remove `\hspace{-0.3cm}`? Even better, could you just get rid of `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\hspace{-0.3cm}}` entirely?

Comment: oh, I created that code long time ago that I don't remember now why I did that, but I promise any code I create in the past is for some reason, and when I create a new project, I usually copy that code from my previous projects, so

Comment: @PermQi - What happens to the numbering of the theorem-like environments if you get rid of `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\hspace{-0.3cm}}`? Please advise.

Comment: you are right, my problem is gone ! this is insane

Comment: @PermQi - Off-topic: The document class option `13pt` has exactly zero effect if the `report` document class is used. The only font size options that the `report` class recognizes are `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`. If you switch from `report` to `extreport`, the class option `14pt` would become available.

Comment: @PermQi - I'm glad the issue has been resolved.

Comment: thank you for really helpful advice. By the way, when I use the code \subsection*{something}, my "something" are not numbered while I want it to be. So how can I number my "something" within the section ?

Comment: @PermQi All "starred" sectioning commands -- `\section*`, `\subsection*`, etc. -- produce unnumbered headers *by design*. Hence, if you do *not* want to suppress the numbering scheme, don't use the starred variants of the commands.

Comment: but I have to use it because I want to use the subsection environment instead of theorem environment (since I think the subsection is easier to use than the theorem), otherwise I don't want to add the subsection into my table of contents, so I used \subsection*.  So let me describe my project's layout for you.   

Chapter 1. Introductory knowledge 
Section 1.1. Linear Algebra 
Subsection 1.1.1. Coordinates and the change of basis
Subsection 1.1.1.1. Definition
Subsection 1.1.1.2. Proposition
Subsection 1.1.2. Orthogonal group
Subsection 1.1.1.2. Definition

Comment: @PermQi - Sorry, but your argument is invalid: LaTeX does *not* impose a rigid connection between what's numbered in the body of the document and what's included in the Table of Contents (ToC). Two facts: (a) If you want to have numbered subsection-level headers in the body of the text, you *must* use `\subsection`, *not* `\subsection*`. (b) If you don't want subsection-level headers to be included in the ToC, just issue the instruction `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` in the preamble. That way, only chapter-level and section-level entries ("level" 0 and 1, resp.) will be included in the ToC.

Comment: wow thank you, I really appreciate. By the way your English is so good, I want to be that good too

Comment: I have used the code ```\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}``` right before the ```\subsection{2.1.1. Definition.}```, but it didn't worked, the subsection is still not hiden in the table of content. What should I do to fix that ?

Comment: @PermQi - Sorry, but I've lost track of which of the many possible permutations of parameter settings we're at. May I ask you to post a *new query*, in which you (a) full and replicable information about your document setup and (b) which outcomes you're trying to a achieve but are somehow stymied at? Thanks.